# How to find a redirect error within hundreds of redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an excel table with over 100 redirects. I copy&pasted them into my htaccess which outputs a 500 error. Now I'm about to test every redirect step by step and as soon as the error occurs, I know which redirect failed.

Is there a way to find the broken redirect more efficiently without testing each redirect one by one?

Comment: Check out this website, it tests `.htaccess` rewrites and will tell you exactly where it fails (if it does) - [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: Check your server's error log, that should contain the details of the 500 error. Incidentally, this is likely to be a syntax error, rather than a "redirect error" as such.